# Есть ли возможность упростить или улучшить код?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Сама задача:

> Старинными английскими мерами длины являются: 1 миля = 1760 ярдов, 1
> ярд = 3 фута, 1 фут = 12 дюймов. Сколько полных миль, ярдов и фунтов
> содержится в А дюймах. Разложите имеющееся количество дюймов на сумму
> из m милей + y ярдов + f футов + i дюймов.

Мой код:

```
A = int(input('Сколько дюймов? '))
m = A // 63360  # миля
b = A % 63360  # остаток от мили
y = b // 36  # ярд
c = y * 36  # остаток от ярда
f = (b - c) // 12  # фут
i = (b - c) % 12  # дюйм
print(str(m) + ' миля ' + str(y) + ' ярда ' + str(f) + ' фута ' + str(i) + ' дюйма.')
```

Comment: Вряд ли. Код достаточно прост и понятен. Да и что тут улучшать? Здесь даже нет ни одного условного ветвления.

Comment: На будущее: в Stack Exchange есть сайт специально для вопросов по улучшению кода: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: `divmod` можно использовать

Comment: Можно улучшить, чтобы не было на выводе "5 миля 1 ярда 10 фута 0 дюйма", например.

Comment: @Глеб [на ruSO разрешен формат вопросов с просьбой код-ревью, для этого в вопросе используется метка `инспекция-кода`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-code-review)

Comment: @Acinit, спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Люблю грамотную речь:

```
def select_form(n, form0, form1, form2):
    if 10 <= n % 100 < 20:
        return form0
    if n % 10 in (0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9):
        return form0
    if n % 10 == 1:
        return form1
    if 2 <= n % 10 <= 4:
        return form2


def format_inches(inches):
    scale = [
        (  12, ('дюймов', 'дюйм', 'дюйма')),
        (   3, ('футов' , 'фут' , 'фута' )),
        (1760, ('ярдов' , 'ярд' , 'ярда' )),
        (None, ('миль'  , 'миля', 'мили' ))
    ]

    parts = []
    n = inches
    for step, forms in scale:
        if step is None:
            u = n
        else:
            n, u = divmod(n, step)
        if u != 0:
            form = select_form(u, *forms)
            parts.append(f'{u} {form}')
    if inches == 0:
        form = select_form(0, *scale[0][1])
        parts.append(f'0 {form}')
    return ' '.join(reversed(parts))


while True:
    print(format_inches(int(input('Сколько дюймов? '))))
```

> ```
> $ python format-inches.py
> Сколько дюймов? 63542
> 1 миля 5 ярдов 2 дюйма
> Сколько дюймов?
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Можно структурировать и упростить решение, использовав словарь с делителями для мер длины, цикл и функцию `divmod()`:

```
A = int(input('Сколько дюймов? '))
d = {'миль': 63360, 'ярдов': 36, 'футов': 12, 'дюймов': 1}  # делители для мер длины
x = A
for key, value in d.items():
    x, y = divmod(x, value)     # divmod возвращает сразу частное от целочисленного деления и остаток
    d[key], x = x, y            # помещаем результат в словарь как значение соответствующей меры длины и присваиваем x частное

print(f'{A} дюймов = {", ".join(f"{value} {key}" for key, value in d.items() if value != 0)}')
```

```
Сколько дюймов? 1234567
1234567 дюймов = 19 миль, 853 ярдов, 1 футов, 7 дюймов
```

Comment: Я опять забыл, питон гарантирует порядок ключей в словаре?

Comment: Да, с версии 3.7 гарантирует https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007169/15035314

Answer (score 1):

Я бы добавил небольшую проверку, что бы не выводить лишние нули.

```py
A = int(input('Сколько дюймов? '))
m = A // 63360  # миля
b = A % 63360  # остаток от мили
y = b // 36  # ярд
c = y * 36  # остаток от ярда
f = (b - c) // 12  # фут
i = (b - c) % 12  # дюйм

result = ''
if m > 0:
    result += str(m) + ' миль '
if y > 0:
    result += str(y) + ' ярд '
if f > 0:
    result += str(f) + ' фут '
if i > 0:
    result += str(i) + ' дюйм.'

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не меняя кардинально структуру - выделить `(b-c)` в отдельную переменную. Мы не можем гарантировать, что подстановка констант сработает так, как мы ожидаем, поэтому вычисления следует хранить, чтобы не вычислять повторно:

```py
A = int(input('Сколько дюймов? '))
m = A // 63360  # миля
b = A % 63360  # остаток от мили
y = b // 36  # ярд
c = y * 36  # остаток от ярда
b_minus_c = b - c
f = b_minus_c // 12  # фут
i = b_minus_c % 12  # дюйм
print(str(m) + ' миля ' + str(y) + ' ярда ' + str(f) + ' фута ' + str(i) + ' дюйма.')
```

Также python имеет встроенную функцию `divmod`, позволяющую превратить 3 строки в 1:

```py
A = int(input('Сколько дюймов? '))
m = A // 63360  # миля
b = A % 63360  # остаток от мили
y = b // 36  # ярд
c = y * 36  # остаток от ярда
f, i = divmod(b-c, 12)
print(str(m) + ' миля ' + str(y) + ' ярда ' + str(f) + ' фута ' + str(i) + ' дюйма.')
```